# how to pass data into an html table in email body in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, mfmailcomposer

I could create the table. But not able to pass the value to table.

```
 - (IBAction)openMail:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailer setSubject:@"Shopping Cart "];


        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fisrtMail@example.com", @"secondMail@example.com", nil];
       [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
       NSString *e=self.phone;
       NSString *f=self.cost;
      //NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",e,@"  ",f,@"  has been purchased successfully"];


    NSString *emailBody=@"<html> <table border=1>      <thead><tr><td>Item</td><td>Name</td><td>Qty</td><td>Price</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>One</td><td>One</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Two</td><td>Two</td><td>Two</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Three</td><td>Three</td><td>Three</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Four</td><td>Four</td><td>Four</td></tr></tbody></table> </html> ";


    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
    //[mailer release];
}
```

I need to pass the value "e" as mentioned above and "f" to the table in html.How to do it? Can you please reply to it.

Comment: What's wrong with using [NSString stringWithFormat:]??

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *emailBody=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <table border=1>      <thead><tr><td>Item</td><td>Phone</td><td>%@</td><td>Cost</td><td>%@><td>Name</td><td>Qty</td><td>Price</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>One</td><td>One</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Two</td><td>Two</td><td>Two</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Three</td><td>Three</td><td>Three</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Four</td><td>Four</td><td>Four</td></tr></tbody></table> </html> ",e,f];
```

in above code i set the e and f with value of Phone and cost see the code...

i hope this help you..

Comment: What's the logic? Why should e and f be globally accessible?

Comment: @Atif see the answer now last answer i post another answer instead of this dude..

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to pass your var(s) values in 'emailBody'. If I'm right than you just format your string like this:

Let say;

```
NSString *myHTMLString = @"some value you need to pass";
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><table><tr><td>%@</td><tr></table></body>",myHTMLString];
```

Please use above according to your HTML formatting.Here, I just give you an example.

Hope this is what you looking for.:)

Answer (score 0):

See:

```
NSString *body = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<html><body><yourHtmlcode />%@ %@</body></html>", yourVar1, yourVar2];
```

You may also create your HTML body dynamically, using loop and concatenation.